# Java Streams - Compose a value depending on values of the list

Tags: java, java-stream

Using Java 8 and working with lists of certain object, using Streams, I need to assign a property to each value of the list depending on properties of other values.

Imagine a class in Java MyClass with these properties:

```
String value1;
String value2;
LocalDate theDate;
String uniqueId;
```

And imagine a list of that MyClass objects, just like:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The property `uniqueId` is empty at the beggining of this exercise.

After mapping the list, the `uniqueId` has to be set following this strategy:

```
<value1>-<value2>-N
```

where `N` is the number of appearances of the `<value1>-<value2>` combination sorted by `theDate`.

Given this example given in JSON:

```
[
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"A", "theDate": "2020-06-01", "uniqueId": null},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"A", "theDate": "2020-06-02", "uniqueId": null},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"A", "theDate": "2020-06-03", "uniqueId": null},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"A", "theDate": "2020-06-04", "uniqueId": null},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"B", "theDate": "2020-06-01", "uniqueId": null},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"B", "theDate": "2020-06-02", "uniqueId": null},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"B", "theDate": "2020-06-03", "uniqueId": null}
]
```

should result after the execution in:

```
[
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"A", "theDate": "2020-06-01", "uniqueId": "1111111-A-1"},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"A", "theDate": "2020-06-02", "uniqueId": "1111111-A-2"},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"A", "theDate": "2020-06-03", "uniqueId": "1111111-A-3"},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"A", "theDate": "2020-06-04", "uniqueId": "1111111-A-4"},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"B", "theDate": "2020-06-01", "uniqueId": "1111111-B-1"},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"B", "theDate": "2020-06-02", "uniqueId": "1111111-B-2"},
{"value1":"1111111", "value2":"B", "theDate": "2020-06-03", "uniqueId": "1111111-B-3"}
]
```

I clearly could do this using a traditional loop strategy. But the question is, using Streams, how do I manage to keep the track of the rest of the values of the list so I can compose my combined value? Or is it not possible using Streams?

```
myList.stream()
    .map(o -> {
    // How do I make here to keep the track of the rest of the values of the list?
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is probably *possible* to do so using streams, but the result will likely be a convoluted mess.  If you need to maintain this code, I would suggest using the more traditional looping method for readability.  Otherwise, you'll likely be re-solving your stream pattern every time you need to make a change.

Comment: You could just use forEach:
myList.stream().forEach(o -> o.setUniqueId("blah"));

Alternatively, implement a "copy" method for your MyClass.

Comment: You _could_ easily create an intermediate `Map<String, List<MyClass>>` where the key is `<value1>-<value2>` via `Collectors.groupingBy`. Then works from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really something were streams shine, and this has two reasons. The first is you are manipulating the `MyClass` objects via side-effects (granted, that could be avoided) and because Java lacks out-of-the-box support for something like `mapWithIndex` or `zipWithIndex`, which would be very helpful here. You can find some more information about how to solve that particlar problem [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-indices).

Anyways, it is possible to do via streams.

First things first, I have defined this helper method:

```
    public static MyClass setUniqueId(MyClass myClass, int i) {
        myClass.uniqueId = String.format("%s-%s-%s", myClass.value1, myClass.value2, i);
        return myClass;
    }
```

It should be fairly self-explanatory - it sets the unique id using the provided int and returns the object itself, now with the id set.

Then, doing what you want is possible by grouping the elements in your stream by equal `value1` and `value2` values. After grouping the elements, we can set their unique Ids by zipping with their index. As Java lacks support for this, we need to do this in a bit of a backwards way by using an `IntStream` with a range that we use to grab indices from. Putting it all together, we get this:

```
        list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> obj.value1 + "-" + obj.value2))
            .forEach((klass, values) -> {
                IntStream.range(0, values.size())
                    .forEach(i -> setUniqueId(values.get(i), i));
        });
```

Another, perhaps more clear approach is to flatMap the result of the grouping:

```
        var results = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> obj.value1 + "-" + obj.value2))
            .values().stream()
            .flatMap(values -> 
                IntStream.range(0, values.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> setUniqueId(values.get(i), i)))
            .sorted((a, b) -> a.date.compareTo(b.date))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Maybe the initial stream should be sequential to keep the sequence. Plus it has to be (i+1) at some point to make the last part of uniqueId start from 1...

Comment: Good answer!! Just one thing... when is it sorting by theDate? It should not assume that, once grouped, the objects are "well" ordered. In other words, the "values" should not be considered as automatically sorted. How would we do it?

Comment: @ElPiter You would do it the same as you would sort any other collection or stream. I have added the sorting in my example since the first mutates the list in-place anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes. I actually had used a Comparator.comparing(Package::getDate) instead of the explicit comparation. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

for simplify I just created a constructor with last parameter.

```
List<MyClass> result = myClasses.stream()
            .collect(() -> new HashMap<String, List<MyClass>>(), (m, myClass) ->
                    m.merge(myClass.getValue2(),

                           //create new value with the current object 
                            new ArrayList<>(singletonList(new MyClass(myClass.getValue1()
                                    + "-" + myClass.getValue2() + "-" +
                                    (m.getOrDefault(myClass.getValue2(),
                                            new ArrayList<>()).size() + 1)))),
                             //merge for duplicate key
                            (l1, l2) -> {l1.addAll(l2);return l1;}),
                    HashMap::putAll)
            .values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I use `HashMap` to store all `myclass` object with the same `value2` property. when I want to create new object from current `myclass` object, consider the map value size for the key(`value2` property).for the absent value I've used `m.getOrDefault(myClass.getValue2(),new ArrayList<>())`